# Proof that: $n! = \Omega (5^{\log n})$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

> Show that: $n! = \Omega (5^{\log n})$

That is to find a $c$ and a $n_0$ such that:
$$n! \geq c\cdot5^{\log n}$$

We have:

$$n!\leq n^n$$

Thus,

$$n\log n \geq \log n \log 5 + \log c$$

Which is:
$$(n - \log 5)\log n \geq \log c$$

So we can pick $c = 1$ and $n_0 = 3$, and it works. Is that right?

Comment: $\Omega(g(n)) = \{ f: \mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{R}^*_{+} | \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^*_{+} s.t. f(n) \geq cg(n)\forall n\geq n_0\}$

Comment: I used $log$ as base 2. As a convention. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: It may be helpful to use $5^{\log n} = n^{\log 5} \leq n^3$.  (I think your values work, but your argument of using $n^n$ doesn't seem to get the inequality the right direction you want)

Comment: Actually I was using the natural log when I evaluated it the first time.  Redoing it base $2$ shows your $n_0$ is too small.  We only get necessary, not sufficient conditions on the parameters by comparing with $n^n$

Comment: Doesn't the definition of $\Omega$ require that there exists a $c>0$, and *arbitrarily large* values of $n$ such that $f(n) \geq c g(n)$, rather than that this inequality holds *for every* $n$ greater than some $n_0$ ? That is, there exists $c>0$ such that for all $n$ there exists an $n' > n$ such that $f(n) \geq c g(n)$ ? This is the negation of the statement that $f(n)$ is $o(g(n))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}n!=\Omega(5^{\log_2n})&\impliedby n!\ge c\cdot5^{\log_2n}=c\cdot n^{\log_25}\quad\forall n\ge n_0\\&\impliedby n(n-1)(n-2)\ge n^{\log_25}\quad (c=1)\\&\impliedby n^{3-\log_25}-\frac3{n^{\log_25-2}}+\frac2{n^{\log_25-1}}\ge1\quad(\log_25\in[2,3])\\&\text{true with}\,n_0=5\end{align}

Comment: Yeah, but my way of solving isn't correct?

Comment: No, because using $n^n$ as an *upper* bound for $n!$ in $n^n\ge c\cdot5^{\log_2n}$ does not say anything about what happens in $n!\ge c\cdot5^{\log_2n}$. In other words, if $a<b$ and we want to prove that $a>c$, simply proving that $b>c$ is insufficient.